# SSIS Import from excel with column names in first column

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005, import, ssis

I have an excel workbook which has numerous worksheets in it. 
Each worksheet has data which represents a schema. 
The problem is that the data is not laid out with a header row, but instead it has a header **"column"**. Also data is only contained in the 7th to 13th row of the sheet i.e.:

```
Field Name  | Swap ID     | Allocation ID | Description | Broker ID ...
Field Type  | Alphanumeric| Alphanumeric  | Alphanumeric| Alphanumeric ...
Field Length| char(40)    | char(40)      | char(100)   | char(50) ....
...
```

How would I go about importing one of these worksheets into a database table with the following structure?

```
Field Name | Field Type | Field Length | ...
```

**NOTE:** My problem is not just skipping down past the row content, but how to "pivot" the data in such a way that my data which is laid out by columns is instead laid out by rows.

**Edit:** Thanks to praveen's answer I am able to handle the requirement for using a specific range of cell's using the `Select * from [Sheet$A7:AZ13]` syntax, but the main problem of importing data which is essentially turned on its side still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Step 1: While creating `Excel Connection Manager` select the option `First Rows as Column name`

Step 2: In excel source use `SQL Command` for `Data access mode` and write the query to skip the initial rows

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A7:B]
```

Comment: This does help with skipping rows, but it does not help with the problem of needing columns transformed to rows (I added a note to my original post to clarify this if my example didn't make this immediately obvious).

Comment: Question: After Row 13, do the sheets contain the actual data in the format of FieldName | FieldType| Field Length....?

Comment: No. Cells A7:A13 contain column header information and Cells B7:AZ13 contain the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many things that can potentially change between one Excel sheet and another. So, use this solution only as startign point.
If you have any question, please let us know. (-; Disclaimer over ;-)

I created an Excel file that looks like this:

> Field Name  | Swap ID     | Allocation ID | Description | Broker ID
>
> Field Type  | Alphanumeric| Alphanumeric  | Alphanumeric| Alphanumeric
>
> Field Length| char(40)    | char(40)      | char(100)   | char(50)

1. Load your Excel file into a staging table (STG_Sheet1).

> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[STG_Sheet1]
>   (
>        [F1] varchar NULL
>       , [F2] varchar NULL
>   , [F3] varchar NULL
>   , [F4] varchar NULL
>   , [F5] varchar NULL 
>   ) ON [PRIMARY]

Now,  Create a new SSIS package.

2.1 Create the following variables:

```
2.1.1 oFieldList; Data type: Object
2.1.2 sColumn; Data type: String, Value: F2
2.1.3 sSql; Data type: String, Value: "SELECT " + @[User::sColumn] + " AS COL FROM [dbo].[STG_Sheet1]"
2.1.4 sSQLInsert; Data type: String
2.1.5 sValues; Data type: String
```

2.2 Place a Script Task.

```
2.2.1 Result Set: Full result set
2.2.2 SQL Statement:
    SELECT sac.name as ColumnName FROM sys.all_columns sac 
        INNER JOIN sys.all_objects sao ON sao.object_id = sac.object_id
        WHERE sao.name = 'STG_Sheet1' AND sac.name <> 'F1'

2.2.3 Result Set: Result Name: 0; Variable Name: User::oFieldList
```

2.3 Place a ForEach Loop Container

```
2.3.1 Enumerator: Foreach ADO Enumerator
2.3.2 ADO object source variable: User::oFieldList
2.3.3 Variable Mappings: User::sColumn: 0
```

Now, inside the ForEach Loop Container

2.4 Place a DFT

```
2.4.1 Place an OLE DB Source
    2.4.1.1 Data access mode: SQL Command from variable
    2.4.1.2 Variable name: sSQL
    2.4.1.3 Columns: COL

2.4.2 Place a Script component as Transformation
    2.4.2.1 Input Columns: COL : ReadOnly
    2.4.2.2 Script: ReadWrite Variables:User::sValues
    2.4.2.3 Edit Script : Code below

    public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
    {
        string colValue = string.Empty;

        public override void PreExecute()
        {
            base.PreExecute();
        }

        public override void PostExecute()
        {
            base.PostExecute();

            string x = Variables.sValues;
            int iFirstCommaAt = colValue.IndexOf (',');
            colValue = colValue.Substring(iFirstCommaAt + 1);
            Variables.sValues = colValue;
        }

        public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
        {
            string x = Row.COL;
            colValue = string.Format("{0},'{1}'", colValue, x);
        }
    }
```

2.5 Place a Script Task:

```
2.5.1 ReadOnlyVariables: User::sValues
2.5.2 ReadWriteVariables: User::sSQLInsert
2.5.3 Edit Script: Code below

    public void Main()
    {
        string s = "INSERT INTO dbo.SHEET1 ([Field Name], [Field Type], [Field Length])  VALUES ";

        string sValue = Dts.Variables["User::sValues"].Value.ToString();
        string sSQLInsert = string.Empty;

        Dts.Variables["User::sSQLInsert"].Value = string.Format("{0} ({1})", s, sValue);

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

2.6 Place an Execute SQL Task

```
2.6.1 SQLSourceTyoe: Variable
2.6.2 SourceVariable: User::sSQLInsert
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also experiment with this:
(After you have loaded the Excel sheet into the staging table, run the following script from the SSMS:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[STG_Sheet1] 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Sheet1]  

DECLARE @CETList2 varchar(300); DECLARE @CETList3 varchar(300);
DECLARE @CETList4 varchar(300); DECLARE @CETList5 varchar(300);
DECLARE @INSERT varchar(1000) DECLARE @EXEC_INSERT varchar(1000);

SET @INSERT = 'INSERT INTO dbo.SHEET1 ([Field Name], [Field Type],[Field Length])  VALUES';

SELECT        
    @CETList2 = COALESCE(@CETList2 + ',', '') + '''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CETL.[F2] AS Varchar))) + '''' 
  , @CETList3 = COALESCE(@CETList3 + ',', '') + '''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CETL.[F3] AS varchar))) + ''''  
  , @CETList4 = COALESCE(@CETList4 + ',', '') + '''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CETL.[F4] AS varchar))) + ''''
  , @CETList5 = COALESCE(@CETList5 + ',', '') + '''' + LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CETL.[F5] AS varchar))) + '''' 
FROM [dbo].[STG_Sheet1] CETL 

SET  @EXEC_INSERT = @INSERT + '(' + @CETList2 + ')';
EXECUTE (@EXEC_INSERT)

SET  @EXEC_INSERT = @INSERT + '(' + @CETList3 + ')'; 
EXECUTE (@EXEC_INSERT)

SET  @EXEC_INSERT = @INSERT + '(' + @CETList4 + ')';
EXECUTE (@EXEC_INSERT)

SET  @EXEC_INSERT = @INSERT + '(' + @CETList5 + ')'; 
EXECUTE (@EXEC_INSERT)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Sheet1]
```